# How to fix this- No source avaliable VS2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am using VS 2010 Ultimate and I am just trying some stuff with the html agility pack.

when I get to one of its built in methods and hit f11 while debugging this comes up

"No Source available"

> Locating source for
>   'C:\Source\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlNode.cs'.
>   Checksum: MD5 {a0 f7 4c 1a 17 ae da d8
>   ca f8 45 63 9d 43 b3 f3} The file
>   'C:\Source\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlNode.cs'
>   does not exist. Looking in script
>   documents for
>   'C:\Source\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlNode.cs'...
>   Looking in the projects for
>   'C:\Source\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlNode.cs'.
>   The file was not found in a project.
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\crt\src\'... Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\'... Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\atl\'... Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\'... The debug source files settings for the active
>   solution indicate that the debugger
>   will not ask the user to find the
>   file:
>   C:\Source\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlNode.cs.
>   The debugger could not locate the
>   source file
>   'C:\Source\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlNode.cs'.

So I am guessing that maybe the .dll is closed and you can't go into it. So can I just have Vs2010 step over it if it can't go over it even if I hit F11?

Instead of when you hit F11 it tries to go in and makes a new tab up with this message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you download the source for the HTML Agility Pack and build it then reference the DLL that you built, you should get source available.